# preg_match no longer is pulling data from file as it was

Tags: php

I was using this following code:

```
<?

$file = file("http://www.schoolclosingsnetwork.com/output/clearchannel/wgyweb.asp");

while ($row = each($file)) {
    $match = preg_match("/\"(.*)\"\,\"(.*)\"/i", $row[1], $matches);
    echo '<b>' . $matches[1] . '</b><br>';
    echo $matches[2] . '<br><br>';
}

if ($match == 0) {
    echo '<p>No announcements found.</p>';
}

?>
```

to pull a feed of school closings and delays, which has been working flawlessly. However, as of today it has stopped working.

The info that it is pulling from is under `$file`

normally what would happen is the output would look like:

**School Name**
Closed/Delayed

now all that I get is that there is No Announcements Found as if it was not finding any matches.

Maybe I'm just overlooking something? I'm not too skilled with PHP as it's not normally integral to my day to day.

So any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that the page template changed?

Comment: Looks like it's working to me http://codepad.viper-7.com/RPD2wB/55dev?

Comment: Wow, that's so weird. I just noticed that it was working on my personal server too. Looks like it's a problem we're having on our end. Thank you so much for checking it out. I've been wracking my brain and just needed another set of eyes I have a feeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you are trying to parse is CSV formatted data. You should use a more appropriate function like [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) to decode it:

```
$file = file("http://www.schoolclosingsnetwork.com/output/clearchannel/wgyweb.asp");

foreach ($file as $row) {
    $matches = str_getcsv($row);
    echo '<b>' . $matches[0] . '</b><br>';
    echo $matches[1] . '<br><br>';
}
```

Comment: This works as well, and is much cleaner and well suited. Root of the problem is an issue we're having right now at work. Either my old code will work or yours will work as well. Thank you so much.